# Is there a way to programatically detect if WiFi AP isolation is in place?

Tags: java, android, c++, ios, wifi

Is there a way to programatically detect if WiFi AP isolation (sometimes called client isolation, too) is in place?

Background: I am maintaining a smartphone app, which uses broadcasts to identify other devices running the same app on the local network. (So that the user can establish a local P2P connection.) I would like to detect if AP isolation is filtering the broadcasts, in order to display helpful 
information to the user.

Comment: I don't think you can check that without having the other device in the network which are able to report you back

Comment: Thank you! Sadly this seems to be correct.